# What is causing my server to issue some DNS requests with extra search domain appended?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, centos5

I have a CentOS 5 box (yes, it's old. Yes, we're upgrading eventually :-D). It has sendmail and a web site (hosted with Jetty).  Our DNS team recently noted that a couple hundred times a day, the server will issue strange dns requests. Specifically, it will issue a query with overlapping domain suffixes.

For example, let's say the hostname of the box is `foobox1.corp.example.domain.net`... we'll see intermittent DNS requests being issued for `foobox1.corp.corp.example.domain.net.corp.example.domain.net`

I checked `/etc/resolv.conf` and it looks fine to me:

```
search corp.example.domain.net
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 2.2.2.2
```

I checked `/etc/hosts` and it also looks fine:

```
# Do not remove the following line, or various programs
# that require network functionality will fail.
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
::1     localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
1.2.3.4     foobox1.corp.example.domain.net
```

It seems to me like SOMETHING on the box is erroneously looking for `foobox1.corp.corp.example.domain.net` and the OS is adding another search domain at the end?

I'm also not sure which process on the system is actually issuing the call -- I mentioned earlier that sendmail and Jetty are installed but there's plenty of other things on the system that could issue DNS queries.

What's the best way to troubleshoot this one? Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

The search list is corp.example.domain.net

If something looks for a.corp, the first query would be a.corp . If it is not found by the DNS, resolver will look for a.corp.corp.example.domain.net

Troubleshoot

- List item
- There's a debug option in resolv.conf. Tried, didn't work for me.
- There's also a ndot option
- stop nscd to test
- what's in nsswitch.conf? make sure where the query goes

try to put search list like below, may relieve half of the problem.

```
search example.domain.net corp.example.domain.net
```